# A program that calculates hourly wage / overtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Question

> Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Pay the hourly rate for the hours up to 40 and 1.5 times the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use `input()` to read a string and `float()` to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input - assume the user types numbers properly.

### Answer

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter hourly rate:")
h = float(hrs)
r = float(rate)
if h <= 40:
    print(h*r)
else:
    print((h-40)*(1.5*r) + (40*r));
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such

Answer (score 1):

Even with a program so simple, there is room for improvement:

Integrate the test given to you. One easy way is via doctests.

Factor out the `r` from your last expression.

Don't name variables `h` and `r`; give human-legible names.

Move the calculation itself into a function with no console input/output.

Consider using `locale` to do proper currency formatting.

Add a `__main__` guard and PEP484 type hints.

Give 1.5 and 40 named constants.

### Suggested

```
from locale import currency, setlocale, LC_ALL, localeconv

PREMIUM = 1.5
NORMAL_HOURS = 40


def get_pay(hours: float, rate: float) -> float:
    """
    Calculate gross pay, accounting for overtime. Hours above NORMAL_HOURS (40) are paid at a
    multiple of PREMIUM (+50%).

    >>> get_pay(hours=20, rate=10)
    200
    >>> get_pay(hours=45, rate=10.50)
    498.75
    """
    if hours > NORMAL_HOURS:
        hours = (hours - NORMAL_HOURS)*PREMIUM + NORMAL_HOURS
    return hours*rate


def main() -> None:
    setlocale(LC_ALL, '')
    currency_sym = localeconv()['currency_symbol']

    pay = get_pay(
        hours=float(input('Hours: ')),
        rate=float(input(f'Hourly rate: {currency_sym}')),
    )
    print('Gross pay:', currency(pay))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```